# Magnitudes of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following question

"Two unit vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}=\frac{1}{2}$ Evaluate the length of $5\vec{x}+3\vec{y}$"

My presumption here is that because a unit vector has magnitude of 1, you just multiply the magnitude of the vectors by the scalars 5 and 3.

So $5\vec{x}+3\vec{y}=5(1)+3(1)=8$

This is how I think it works but it seems too easy. Is there any properties of magnitudes of vectors that I'm missing that are pertinant to the question or is it really that easy?

Comment: Note:  The magnitude of the sum of a unit vector in the x-direction in $\Bbb R^3$ and a unit vector in the y-direction in $\Bbb R^3$ is $\sqrt2$, not $2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving without arrows: Let $l$ be the length of $5x+3y$. Then

$$l^2=(5x+3y) \cdot(5x+3y)=25 x \cdot x+30 x \cdot y+9 y \cdot y.$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I must remember that the dot product of two vectors is equal to the square of the magnitude or length of said vectors. Also to keep in mind the properties of the dot product operation

Answer (score 2):

What you've done is true, if you assume that $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ point in the same direction.

The key piece of information is that $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=\frac{1}{2}$. One way to represent the dot product is $||\vec{x}||\,||\vec{y}||\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. Since the length of $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are both 1, that tells you that $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}$, or $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

With that information, you should be able to make a right triangle where two sides and two angles are known, which is sufficient information to find the third side (which is the answer you're looking for).

Answer (score 1):

Given $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2,..x_n), \vec{y} = (y_1, y_2, ..y_n)$. Since $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ are unit vectors $x_1^2+x_2^2...x_n^2=1$ and $y_1^2+y_2^2...y_n^2=1$. Given $\langle x, y \rangle = x_1y_1+x_2y_2+..+x_ny_n = \frac{1}{2}$.

Let $\vec{z} = 5\vec{x}+3\vec{y}=(5x_1+3y_1, 5x_2+3y_2,..5x_n+3y_n)$. Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
{\lVert z \rVert}^2 &= {\lVert 5\vec{x}+3\vec{y} \rVert}^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (5x_i+3y_i)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} 25x_i^2 + 9y_i^2+30x_iy_i\\
&= 25 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 + 9 \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2 + 30 \langle \vec{x},\vec{y} \rangle \\
&= 25+9+15 \\
&= 49
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Therefore $\lVert z \rVert = 7$. So, the length of $5\vec{x}+3\vec{y}$ is $7$, not 8.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Fred is -- in my opinion -- the best. Nevertheless, one may also turn toward high school geometry. We know the cosine between the two vectors, and the two vectors are situated in a 2-dimensional linear subspace which is isometric to the Euclidean Plane. Thus, we can use the cosine theorem (which is a generalization of the Pythagoras Theorem).

Comment: Thanks. I believe I answered the question correctly using @Fred reply. But I'm not sure what you mean here. Do you mean using the Law of Cosines to solve the problem using the angle between the two vectors ($\frac{1}{2}$ and the magnitude of the scalar multiples of the two sides ($5\vec{x}+3\vec{y}$)?

Comment: Yes, the Law of Cosines.

Answer (score 0):

Magnitude of a vector $|\vec x| = \sqrt{\vec x\cdot \vec x}$. And then you should use the linearity of scalar product.